# filling two spinners based on selection of the first

Tags: android, arrays

i am trying to populate two spinners based on the selection of the first so when i choose one of the options in the first spinner the second one is filled with the appropriate string array. I am kind of new in android and i can't find the mistake, i am getting an error on createFromResource inside the if loop . Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.locations, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.locations, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position==5) {
                Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                        R.array.startlocations, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else{
                Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                        R.array.destinations, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
            }


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.destinations, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

I think this is your problem
try replacing with

```
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ActivityClassName.this,
                    R.array.destinations, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

where "ActivityClassName" is the name of you activity

Comment: thank you that seemed to do the trick!!!
so simple and yet i couldn't find it. Thanks again.

Comment: for future reference context variable is an activity or an app

so never use "this" inside an inner class as it reference the inner class itself

this can drive you crazy